# XAMPP Virtualhost doesn't route

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, routes, xampp

I've a project where all requests are sent to index.php with routing in the .htaccess file.

This unfortunately doesn't work in XAMPP Virtualhost.
But when I go to the root folder and execute the command `PHP -S 127.0.0.1:8080` or any other port, the routing system works and the .htaccess file also works.
That proves that there isn't anything wrong with my PHP Code. 
To clarify: I can reach the virtualhost and it does work. 
But when I'd add `/control`, it says "Object not found", because `control.php` doesn't exist. But it should take me to the control page, because it should sent the request to `index.php`. 
The .php extension removal does work, so `/client` does work, because there's a file named `client.php`. So the .htaccess isn't being ignored on that. 

I've also tried typing some random stuff in the .htaccess file and see if it would give me a server error and it actually did. So that also proves the Virtualhost doesn't ignore the .htaccess file. 

My  .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d            
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f        
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?q=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The httpd-vhosts.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/example"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    <Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\example">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Does anyone know a solution to this?

With kind regards, 
**EDIT 1** 
I added to `httpd-vhosts.conf` the line `DirectoryIndex index.php`and it know looks like this:

```
<Directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\example">
     DirectoryIndex index.php
     AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

**EDIT 2** 
After some testing, I found out that the routing rule for `/login` does work. 
My `index.php` file:

```
<?php
// For Routing, I use the library AltoRouter: https://altorouter.com/
session_start();
require '../vendor/autoload.php';
require __DIR__ .'/includes/PHP/logout.inc.php';
$router = new AltoRouter();
$router->map('GET', '/', function() {
    require __DIR__ . '/homepage.php';
});
$router->map('GET', '/405', function() {
    echo '405';
});
$router->map('GET', '/login', function() {
    require __DIR__ .  '/login.php';
});
$router->map('GET', '/beheer', function() {

    require __DIR__ . '/beheer.php';
});
$router->map('POST', '/uitloggen', function() {
    $confirmation = TRUE;
    logout($confirmation);
});
$router->map('GET', '/client/[i:id]', function() {
    require __DIR__  ."/client.php";
});
$router->map('GET', '/car/*', function() {
    require __DIR__ . "/auto.php";
});
$match = $router->match();
if(is_array($match) && is_callable($match['target'])) {
    call_user_func_array($match['target'], $match['params']);
} else {
    echo '404';
}
```

When I changed the rule for `/login`, to `echo 'login'`, it actually printed the 'login' message, so this also proves that it kind of works, but not fully for some reason. 
And when I change the `/beheer` rule to `/control`, (`control.php` exists), and then I change the `require __DIR__ . '/control.php` line to `echo 'control`, it prints the 'control' message. 
So it seems like XAMPP is only redirecting to `index.php`, if the path in the url is valid and exists. 
Any way to solve this? 
**EDIT 3 AND SOLUTION**

 After a while, I realised I could also just sent all 404 errors `index.php` file and then I would handle the real 404 errors in the `index.php` file. 
So I just added: `ErrorDocument 404 index.php` to the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to set the `DirectoryIndex` directive offered by the index module to also consider your `index.php` routing script: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html

Comment: @arkascha I've set the ```DirectoryIndex``` in ```httpd-vhosts.conf```` and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use [OpenServer](https://biblprog.org.ua/ru/open_server/). Don't waste time on xampp it will take you forever and never solve its routing problems.